# Extract multiple HTML tables by table name using Perl

Tags: perl

I have some HTML files and I wish to extract two tables from each file. Is it possible to extract from both tables in one sweep?

The column headers are slightly different, this script  works but looks a bit long winded, is there any way i can have 'Schedule Name | Node Name' as a header for the last column and get both tables in one go.? tabes are depth/count 2.1 and 2.2.

```
<code>
  #!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
#use diagnostics;
use HTML::TableExtract;
use Text::Table;

##my $sched = qr/Schedule Name|Node Name/;
my $html = "c:\\Testin.htm";
my $out = "c:\\Testout.csv";
open( my $ofh, ">", $out ) or die "oops" ;
 my  $headers =  [ 'Status', 'Results', 'Schedule Name'];
my $table_extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => $headers);
my $table_output = Text::Table->new();
$table_extract->parse_file($html);
my ($table) = $table_extract->tables or die "no emails to process\n";

foreach  my $row ($table->rows) {
       $table_output->load($row);
     print "   ", join(',',grep defined, @$row), "\n";
print $ofh "   ", join(',',grep defined, @$row ), "\n";
}
   $headers =  [ 'Status', 'Results', 'Node Name'];
 $table_extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => $headers);
 $table_output = Text::Table->new();

$table_extract->parse_file($html);
 ($table) = $table_extract->tables;

foreach my $row ($table->rows) {
       $table_output->load($row);
     print "   ", join(',',grep defined, @$row),"\n";
print $ofh "   ", join(',',grep defined, @$row), "\n";
}

<code>
```

Comment: What are the actual table headers?

Comment: What do you mean by *"is it posible to extract the tables by name"*? The `<table>` element doesn't support a `name` attribute, although you could use the `id` attribute.

Comment: Table names are Administrative Schedules & ClientSchedules.       column names are [ 'status', 'Results', 'Schedule Name'];             [ 'status', 'Results', 'Node Name'];

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what you mean by the table *"name"* (HTML `<table>` elements can't have a `name` attribute) but if the two tables' headers are as shown in the code then you can simply write

```
my $table_extract = HTML::TableExtract->new(headers => [qw/ status Results Name /])
```

as a header will match if it *contains* any of the strings in the `headers` array. It is also a case-insensitive match.

Comment: [qw/ status Results Name /]) only extracts the first table column headers.

Comment: I didn't know this was a game! Okay I've guessed what's in your HTML, now you guess what's wrong with your program. I'll tell you when you're getting warmer.